# Rubyでモデルの親子関係を調べたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ER図上で親子関係(依存関係)になっているものを、Rubyのソース上で本当にそうなっているのかの解析を行っています。
しかし、Rubyのソース内の関連付けを行っているモデルの中で、親子関係になっているものの判定方法が分かりません。
以下のような例で、親子関係を判定することはできるのでしょうか？
これで分かるのは、リレーションと、モデル間で参照があるかどうかだけかと考えています。

例1：

```
class HogeGroup
  has_many :hoge_data, :class_name => 'HogeData', :foreign_key => 'hoge_id'

class HogeData
  belongs_to :hoge_group, :class_name => 'HogeGroup', :foreign_key => 'hoge_id'
```

例2：

```
class TestGroup
  #has_manyの記載なし

class TestData
  belongs_to :test_group, :class_name => 'TestGroup', :foreign_key => 'test_id'
```

Rubyのソース上で解析できる方法があれば、ご教示頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「親子関係(依存関係)」と「関連づけ」と「リレーション」と「モデル間で参照」をそれぞれ異なる物として認識されているようですが、あなたの認識ではそれぞれが具体的にどのようなものか、またはどのように違うのかを説明して頂けますか。

Answer (score 0):

`reflect_on_all_associations`メソッドが使えると思います。`ActiveRecord::Reflection::XXXReflection`のインスタンスの配列が返ってきます。

```
HogeGroup.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
  #=> [<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyToReflection>]

HogeData.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)
  #=> [<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection>]
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#M001861

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024205/rails-method-to-get-the-association-name-of-a-model